# Navigation inside TabHost

Tags: android, xamarin, tabs, mvvmcross

I have a problem with the navigation: I created a tabbed application using `MvxTabsFragmentActivity` and all worked great until I start navigating inside the tabs; If I navigate one level inside one tab and then I change the tab, on the second tab I am presented with the content from the first tab. Have anyone encountered this problem?

I created the tabs using `TabHost`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/actualtabcontent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tabContainer"/>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/tabContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <TabHost android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="7dp"
                android:background="@drawable/gradient_border_top"
                android:orientation="horizontal" />

                <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                     android:orientation="horizontal"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                     android:layout_height="56dp"
                     android:layout_weight="0"
                     android:background="@color/white" />

                <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                     android:layout_width="0dp"
                     android:layout_height="0dp"
                     android:layout_weight="0" />
              </LinearLayout>
        </TabHost>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Each time I am navigating inside the tabs the content of actualtabcontent is replaced.

Expected navigation:

Tab A: A1 -> A2.

Tab B: B1 -> B2.

Switching between tabs should display the content for the selected tab

Answer (score 0):

'You need to clear the cache while moving to the next tab.
if you are getting data from server using volley then use'

```
stringRequest.setShouldCache(false);
```

'before passing your stringrequest to requestqueu.'

'if you are using something else then find a way to clear cache before loading new data.'

'hope you get the answer if not please explain your question.'

Comment: I am not using volley library. The architecture of the app is made using MvvmCross and I created a custom HttpWrapper class, in Core project, for making the calls to server.

Comment: I think this should be helpful for you. [Click](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/1986)

Comment: It did not fit on my problem. Thanks anyway.